# Passing array of vec2 to Fragment Shader Opengl es 2.0

Tags: ios, opengl-es, fragment-shader, uniform

I am trying to pass in an array of vec2 to a fragment shader but i can't seem to work out how.

In my application i have the following array.

```
GLfloat myMatrix[] = { 100.0, 100.0,
    200.0, 200.0 };

glUniformMatrix2fv(matrixLocation, 2, 0, myMatrix);
```

and in my fragment shader i am trying to access those values like so

```
uniform vec2 myMatrix[2];

gl_FragColor = gl_FragCoord.xy + myMatrix[0].xy;
```

however the fragcolor does not change which it should as if i hard code it to

```
gl_FragColor = gl_FragCoord.xy + vec2( 100.0, 100.0 ).xy;
```

Any ideas how i can pass these vec2 values into the shader

Thanks in advance

Comment: glUniform2f(UniformLocation, X, Y)

Comment: I need to pass in an array of items, each having two values. so that i can fill up my myMatrix array and loop through the values.

Comment: I worked this out in my main method 

    GLfloat pointArray[2][2];
    glUniform2fv(uniformIndex, 2, (GLfloat *)&pointArray);

and inside the shader

    uniform vec2 points[10];

Hope this helps someone else out.

Comment: Why not put the answer in the answer box instead of comment, so that it were easier accessible to the readers and the question didn't not look unanswered?